# communal wifi (PS3 & SkyHD)

Tags: wireless-networking

I am using communal WiFi which requires web page log in interface. I need advice on what software/hardware i need to allow my PS3(pain to log into via the ps3 browser) and Sky HD( has no browser to log in) to connect to a device  i.e bridge or router or pc sharing wifi without the need for these deives to use the login interface.

I would be looking into maybe a bridge/router device or virtual router maybe.

I current have a Edimax EW-7811UN 150Mbps Wireless Nano USB Adapter running on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Talk to the admin, ask if (s)he will whitelist your devices, would be the least annoying way.

Imo if you buy a device, I say TP-Link, because they are cheap, featurerich and if they cant trigger wifi-webportals with their normal options, you can install OpenWRT or DDWRT, where you can script that.